# How can I auto-insert semi-colon and colon after property autocompletion in css-mode?

Tags: company-mode, completion, css

Inside a CSS declaration, you got the *property*, the part before the colon, that can mostly always be auto-completed:

```
strong {
  color: red;  /* <= color is the property */
}
```

After hitting return from the menu of your completion tool (let's say [Company](https://company-mode.github.io/)), it is very likely you will type`:`, the value of your property and then `;`.

What I think of is that, after hitting return, the colon and semicolon should be auto-inserted and then the point should be positioned right before the semicolon:

```
/* Point position before completion */
strong {
  /*  v */
  colo    
}

/* Point position after completion */
strong {
  /*     v */
  color: ;    
}
```

Any hints about this?

Note: I saw this behavior in Atom CSS plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by having the css-mode's `completion-at-point-functions` return an appropriatr `:exit-function` property which inserts ": ;" and puts point just before the semi-colon (which it's called with a `finished` status).

Maybe a patch along the lines of:

```
diff --git a/lisp/textmodes/css-mode.el b/lisp/textmodes/css-mode.el
index 9e36a88..f8ee3ec 100644
--- a/lisp/textmodes/css-mode.el
+++ b/lisp/textmodes/css-mode.el
@@ -687,7 +687,8 @@ css--font-lock-keywords
        ;; Even though pseudo-elements should be prefixed by ::, a
        ;; single colon is accepted for backward compatibility.
        "\\(?:\\(:" (regexp-opt (append css-pseudo-class-ids
-                                       css-pseudo-element-ids) t)
+                                       css-pseudo-element-ids)
+                               t)
        "\\|\\::" (regexp-opt css-pseudo-element-ids t) "\\)"
        "\\(?:([^)]+)\\)?"
        (if (not sassy)
@@ -921,10 +922,22 @@ css-completion-at-point
       (seq-let (prop-beg prop-end prop-table) (css--complete-property)
         (seq-let (sel-beg sel-end sel-table) (css--complete-selector)
           (when (or prop-table sel-table)
+            ;; FIXME: If both prop-table and sel-table are set but
+            ;; prop-beg/prop-end is different from sel-beg/sel-end
+            ;; we have a problem!
             `(,@(if prop-table
                     (list prop-beg prop-end)
                   (list sel-beg sel-end))
-              ,(completion-table-merge prop-table sel-table)))))))
+              ,(completion-table-merge prop-table sel-table)
+              :exit-function
+              ,(lambda (string status)
+                 (and (eq status 'finished)
+                      prop-table
+                      (test-completion string prop-table)
+                      (not (and sel-table
+                                (test-completion string sel-table)))
+                      (progn (insert ": ;")
+                             (forward-char -1))))))))))

 ;;;###autoload
 (define-derived-mode css-mode prog-mode "CSS"
```

could do the trick.

Comment: Found in css-mode.el : ;;; Todo:

;; - electric ; and }

Comment: "Todo" since 2006 at least

Comment: FWIW, I believe this todo item is outdated because it referred to the auto-indentation kind of "electricity", which has been implemented in the mean time in `css-electric-keys`.